# Enumerate Horizontally with multicols

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I would like to have a maths exercise in a document so that the questions are numbered thus:

```
1. Question 1
     a) subquestion 1      b) subquestion 2    c)subquestion 3
     d) subquestion 4      e) subquestion 5    f)subquestion 6
     etc.

2. Question 2
```

I've managed to achieve something similar using the `multicols` package, but this renders the letters in vertical order, rather than horizontal. The code of my attempt is detailed below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Exercise 18.1}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Prove the following by induction on $n$, where $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.     
        \begin{enumerate}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
            \item $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n 2^r=2^{n+1}-1$
            \item $5+5^2+\cdots+5^n=\displaystyle\frac{5(5^n-1)}{4}$
            \item $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n a^r=\frac{a(a^n-1)}{a-1};~a\in\mathbb R$\\
            \item The sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$.    
            \end{multicols}         
            \item $\displaystyle(1+a)+2(2+a)+3(3+a)+\cdots+n(n+a)=\frac{n}{6}(n+1)(3a+2n+1);~a\in\mathbb R$
            \item $5(4)+6(5)+7(6)+\cdots+n(n-1)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}(n^3-n-60);~\forall n\geq 5$
            \item $1^4+2^4+3^4+\cdots+n^4=\displaystyle\frac{n}{30}(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$
        \end{enumerate}     
        \item Prove the following statements by induction.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \item $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n r^5=\frac{n^2}{12}(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)$
                \item $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{r}{r+1}$
                \item $\displaystyle\prod_{r=1}^n r^{12}=(r!)^{12}$
            \end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which renders the following output:
[image: Output]
Anyone know how I can achieve the horizontal ordered numbering?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `tasks` package is made for that. I added `enumitem`, to easily customise the `enumerate` environment (`wide` option). Also, I simplifies your your code with `everymath{\displaystyle}`at the beginning of the `enumerate` environment. The labels can be easily customised with the `counter-format` key. Last, not least, if an item is longer than one column, it it is typed as a `\parbox`. Alternatively, you can let it spread for more than one column with the star version of `\tasks`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Exercise 18.1}
\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt]\everymath{\displaystyle}
  \item Prove the following by induction on $n$, where $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.
        \begin{tasks}(2)
          \task $\sum_{r=0}^n 2^r=2^{n+1}-1$
          \task $5+5^2+\cdots+5^n=\frac{5(5^n-1)}{4}$
          \task $\sum_{r=0}^n a^r=\frac{a(a^n-1)}{a-1};~a\in\mathbb R$\\
          \task The sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$.
          \task* $(1+a)+2(2+a)+3(3+a)+\cdots+n(n+a)=\frac{n}{6}(n+1)(3a+2n+1);~a\in\mathbb R$
          \task* $5(4)+6(5)+7(6)+\cdots+n(n-1)=\frac{1}{3}(n^3-n-60);~\forall n\geq 5$
          \task* $1^4+2^4+3^4+\cdots+n^4=\frac{n}{30}(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)$
        \end{tasks}
  \item Prove the following statements by induction.
        \begin{tasks}[counter-format={\bfseries tsk[1].}](2)
          \task $\sum_{r=1}^n r^5=\frac{n^2}{12}(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)$
          \task $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{r}{r+1}$
          \task $\prod_{r=1}^n r^{12}=(r!)^{12}$

        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! And if need be, how would I change the labels? (to roman/arabic for example)

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to customise the label, and added a few details.

Comment: Thanks for this! It's great. I'm having trouble getting it to work with other labels though. For example, if I use the option 

[counter-format={tsk[i].}]

to try to produce i., ii,..., I get an error.

And if I use the option

[counter-format={(tsk[a])}]

to try to produce (a), (b),...

then there is no space between the heading and the entry.

Comment: @user93370: To have a `roman` counter, the syntax is `[counter-format={tsk[r].}]`. For the second problem, add something like `[label-width=1.5em]`.