# How to change layout of multicols together enumerate command?

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I have been using `multicol` in my lists of exercises. But I'm trying to change the layout of the column. Rather than

```
a) xxx d) xxx g) xxx

b) xxx e) xxx h) xxx

c) xxx f) xxx i) xxx
```

for instance, I would like

```
a) xxx b) xxx c) xxx

d) xxx e) xxx f) xxx

g) xxx h) xxx i) xxx
```

Is it possible to use with my particular commands?

In time, I was trying to use [Enumerate Horizontally with multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287335/enumerate-horizontally-with-multicols) but I believe this question is different and I don't know how to change it for me.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}%{\article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\dis}{\displaystyle}

\newcounter{theeq} \setcounter{theeq}{0}
\newcommand{\eq}{ 
    \

    \noindent 
    \refstepcounter{theeq}\textbf{\arabic{theeq}}. }


\begin{document}

\eq Calcule
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[$(a)$, leftmargin=3.2em]
        \item $\dis \int  (\sqrt{x^3}+ \sqrt[3]{x^2}) \;dx$
        \item $\dis \int\, \dfrac{x^9 + 4x^3 -6x^2 + 3}{x^5}\ dx $
        \item $\dis \int\, \dfrac{1+x}{1+x^2}\;dx $
        \item $\int x\sqrt{1-x^2}\;dx$
        \item $\int x^2 \;dx$
        \item $\int \cos(x)\;dx$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

Is it possible like bellow?

\setcounter{theeq}{0}

\eq Calcule
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[$(a)$, leftmargin=3.2em]
        \item $\dis \int  (\sqrt{x^3}+ \sqrt[3]{x^2}) \;dx$
        \item $\dis \int\, \dfrac{x^9 + 4x^3 -6x^2 + 3}{x^5}\ dx $
        \item $\dis \int\, \dfrac{1+x}{1+x^2}\;dx $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[, leftmargin=3.2em]
        \item[$(d)$] $\int x\sqrt{1-x^2}\;dx$
        \item[$(e)$] $\int x^2 \;dx$
        \item[$(f)$] $\int \cos(x)\;dx$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this sort of thing.  just to illustrate the point...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}%{\article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}% added showframe for demonstration
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\dis}{\displaystyle}

\newcounter{theeq} \setcounter{theeq}{0}
\newcommand{\eq}{\par\refstepcounter{theeq}\textbf{\arabic{theeq}}.~}

\newcounter{block}[theeq]% auto-reset
\newcommand{\block}[1]{% #1 = equation to solve (math mode)
  \refstepcounter{block}% assuming you might want to use \label inside #1
  \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{(\alph{block})\hspace{\labelsep}}% \labelwidth and \labelsep are used by \item
  \makebox[\dimexpr \textwidth/3-\leftskip/3-\labelwidth][l]{$\displaystyle #1$}%
  \allowbreak\ignorespaces}

\newenvironment{myindent}{\parindent=0pt
  \par
  \raggedright% for roundoff errors
  \leftskip=3.2em}{\par}

\begin{document}

\eq Calcule
\begin{myindent}
  \block{\int  (\sqrt{x^3}+ \sqrt[3]{x^2}) \;dx}%
  \block{\int\, \dfrac{x^9 + 4x^3 -6x^2 + 3}{x^5}\ dx}%
  \block{\int\, \dfrac{1+x}{1+x^2}\;dx }%
  \block{\int x\sqrt{1-x^2}\;dx}
  \block{\int x^2 \;dx}
  \block{\int \cos(x)\;dx}
\end{myindent}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to the problems I wanted. If someone wants to know how I did, follow the code.

Thanky you for your time (and my apologies for the inconvenience).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}%{\article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newcounter{theeq} \setcounter{theeq}{0}
\newcommand{\eq}{ 
    \

    \noindent 
    \refstepcounter{theeq}\textbf{\arabic{theeq}}. }


\begin{document}

\eq Calcule
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[$(a)$, leftmargin=3.2em]\everymath{\displaystyle}
        \item $ \int  (\sqrt{x^3}+ \sqrt[3]{x^2}) \;dx$
        \item $ \int\, \dfrac{x^9 + 4x^3 -6x^2 + 3}{x^5}\ dx $
        \item $ \int\, \dfrac{1+x}{1+x^2}\;dx $
        \item $ \int x^2\sqrt{1-x}\;dx$
        \item $\int x^2 \;dx$
        \item $\int \cos(x)\;dx$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}



\setcounter{theeq}{0}

\eq Calcule
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=$(tsk[a])$,item-indent=3.5em, label-offset=1.00em, ](3)%
    \task $ \int  (\sqrt{x^3}+ \sqrt[3]{x^2}) \;dx$
    \task $ \int\, \dfrac{x^9 + 4x^3 -6x^2 + 3}{x^5}\ dx $
    \task $ \int\, \dfrac{1+x}{1+x^2}\;dx $
    \task \label{eqd} $ \int x^2\sqrt{1-x}\;dx$
    \task $\int x^2 \;dx$
    \task $\int \cos(x)\;dx$
\end{tasks}

(Hint: In \ref{eqd} use that $u = 1-x$)

\end{document}
```