# Enumerate Horizontally with multicols and span a column

Tags: multirow, tasks

Follow up to question [Enumerate Horizontally with multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287335/enumerate-horizontally-with-multicols).

I want one of my entries to span a column. That last task doesn't quite fit in a column.

```
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $\ds \frac{d}{dx} \int_3^x e^{5t}\,dt$

\task $\ds \frac{d}{dx} \int_x^{-7} \sec^3 t\,dt$

\task $\ds \frac{d}{dx} \int_1^{\sin x} (\sqrt{t} + t^3)\,dt$

\task $\ds \frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^{x^2} t^5\,dt$

\task $\ds \int_3^x e^{5t}\,dt$. (Careful! It's not the same as part (a).)
\end{tasks}
```

Comment: What you want is not quite clear to me. Do you want the last task to span over two columns or to be multilined within its column?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do either, but anyways did you try the \task* version?

Comment: @hesham : \task* is what he want, I guess! You should better answer to his question

Comment: @Bernard at hesham Sorry, didn't realize all the options possible. I want the last task to span two columns. I will check out \task* now.

Comment: @Say OL Thanks! I was just lazy to answer here with a lot of distant leanings! Anyway I am not sure it solved his problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the `\task*` version with asterisk instead of `\task`. That's it.